# What could cause CKEditor icons to go missing?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, icons, ckeditor

When the browser is IE9 and it has a horizontal scrollbar, sometimes icons go missing from my CKEditor.  This happens especially during Undo and when switching between source mode and back. The horrible part is that I can't replicate it outside my site (sorry no linking), but I can replicate it easily within it by simply adding a table and then pressing undo. The icons come back when I move my mouse over them (Maby I should do a video to demonstrate?).

I have no idea what is causing this so any suggestions are welcome. I don't touch the icons in my custom code at all. Have you seen a similar issue to this? What could be causing it? Is there anything I can try?

Added: [**YouTube demonstration of the issue happening**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxEKAC3GyIs)

Missing icons:

[image: Missing icons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it indeed was some insanity inducing IE9 rendering bug with CSS `opacity`.

For others experiencing this bug: I fixed it by manually editing the CKEditor `editor_ie.css`. There is a part like this: `.cke_button_disabled .cke_button_icon{opacity:.3}`. All I did was comment out the opacity, leaving `.cke_button_icon{/* opacity:.3 Removed By Nenotlep */}`.

Note that a "fix" like this is a **Bad Idea**, you have to remember to manually maintain the change in your code repository.

Comment: Removing styles for disabled buttons doesn't seem to be ideal solution, but if you can't find another it's acceptable. You can try with replacing it with `filter: alpha(opacity = 30);` instead. BTW. is your site working in standards mode?

Comment: Yeah it's in standards mode. I noticed that `filter: alpha` is used sometimes, sometimes opacity is used and sometimes both - that surprised me. Especially strange was that after commenting out that CSS style, it made no difference on the UI. The disabled buttons are still nicely gray - it looks like at least in IE9 and chrome my change had no effect at all on the UI except that now the bug disappeared!

Comment: Perhaps there are overlapping styles for normal browsers (including IE9) and old IEs. BTW. I think that you can accept your answer.

Comment: Yeah that might be why it still works as expected. I still have to wait 2hrs before accepting :). Thanks for all your assistance yet again!

Answer (score 0):

Very weird. Seems that disabled buttons lose their icons. I see that you modified CSS a little bit - haven't you overwritten path to icons strip for disabled buttons as well? Or have you updated CKEditor installation recently, but without stylesheet you modified earlier? Maybe this is a cache issue - path is the same, but IE9 remembers old file where those icons were in different positions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We can safely say that it's not a cache issue. Yeah I have modified the CSS, but nothing about the icons, I just stretched the dropdowns (I have a massive list of items with very long names). Tomorrow I'll try to revert all my stylesheet changes and have a look if that has any effect. I don't think that it will, because everything works well if there is no horizontal scrollbar on the window - that is the key that triggers this problem. I'll also look 404. I forgot to mention that the icons appear again if I mouse over them - maybe I should create a demo video.

Comment: I added a YT link to the question to demonstrate it better. Any ideas? I checked network capture and nothing went between the server and the client during this. My CSS mods are just `.cke_combo_text { width:110px !important; }` and similar for `combopanel` - that's it.

Comment: Heh... Looks just like some IE9's bug ;/ Hard to tell anything useful. You need to either debug this on your own or report as a bug on CKE's trac, but you would need to prepare a sample.

Comment: That's why I didn't create a trac issue: because I couldn't prepare a sample, so I decided to ask here instead :).  I've tried to debug this but I have no idea what to look for next. I did notice that the use of CSS `opacity` and `filter` looks inconsistent in `editor_ie.css`, for some rules only opacity is used, for some both and for some only filter is used. If that file is for IE9+, shouldn't they all be the same? A new observation: if the content is `<p>a</p><p></p>' and I put the table so that it replaces the second paragraph, this bug does not appear and icons are just fine.

Comment: you were right, it was an IE9 rendering bug due to CSS opacity that I "fixed" with a simple and stupid out-comment that might very well break IE7-8/10 but I can't test it. I debugged it by removing all opacity and alpha filters and then replacing them with border and background colors until I found the one that failed.